# Get rid of "Choose application" dialog when app couldn't be found in AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I need to to get rid of that annoying dialog. How can I achieve that?

I'm trying to get an window title of the active application. Sometimes there are applications which has valid app name but when I try to insert it into the AppleScript script(for window title retrieving) that dialog is appeared. I need just to ignore those application without bothering an end-user with that dialog.

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is sometimes an issue, therefore we can target applications by their bundle id, which will remove the confusion. Try it this way.

```
set bundleName to "com.apple.TextEdit"

-- find out if the application is running
set appIsRunning to false
tell application "System Events"
    try
        first process whose bundle identifier is bundleName
        set appIsRunning to true
    end try
end tell

if appIsRunning then
    tell application id bundleName
        -- do something
    end tell
end if
```

Here's a little script to help you find the bundle id of an application.

```
try
    tell application "Finder" to set bundleID to id of (choose file)
on error
    return "The chosen file is not an application"
end try
return bundleID
```

Finally, I'm not sure this will help your problem. If you have a "tell application whatever" line in your code, and the user does not have whatever application on their system, then it's likely that the dialog will launch anyway. That's the way applescript has always worked. Apple has tried to fix this issue and most programs no longer show the "find application" window however some still do. iPhoto is one example I've noticed.

It happens when you distribute your code as a script, because when a script opens it has to compile itself. During the compile phase applescript needs to ensure the code is correct and therefore to check the code the application's applescript dictionary must be checked... which means sometimes the application must be launched. However there is one possible solution. You must deliver your script pre-compiled which means you must distribute it as an application instead of a script. In addition you must use the following construct in the application. So in other words, you will pre-compile the script on your computer with the "using terms from" stuff so the user doesn't have to check the application's dictionary when they run it.

```
set appName to "TextEdit"

using terms from application "TextEdit"
    tell application appName
        -- do something
    end tell
end using terms from
```

Comment: thanks! "tell application id bundleName" is actually what I've searched for. I do have bundle id from my Cocoa part.

Comment: Please read the rest of my post which might impact you also. I added new stuff to the post.

Comment: Note that the current AppleScript Editor's default file format for scripts - `*.scpt` - is _precompiled as well_. Also, I don't think it makes a difference (at least on Mountain Lion) whether you use `using terms from` or not - as long as you run a precompiled script (whether a `*.scpt` file with `osascript` or an `*.app` file directly), you should be fine, as the dialog only pops up during _compilation_.